# Escaping of rails-generated URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an issue creating a link to reset a password. I have the following in my email view:

```
<%= link_to "Reset password", edit_password_reset_url(@user.reset_token,
                                  email: @user.email) %>
```

The link generated into the log is

```
<a href=3D"http://localhost:3000/password_resets/RtukKzGZ9U8HOaHyipTmYw/e=
dit?email=3Demail%40gmail.com">Reset password</a>
```

The escaping of the link does not seem right (I have this "3D" and an "=" which got erronesouly added to the URL). As a result, I get a "no routes found" error when I paste the link in my browser. If I manually change the link into

```
http://localhost:3000/password_resets/RtukKzGZ9U8HOaHyipTmYw/e
dit?email=email%40gmail.com
```

The link will work. Would anyone know why the escaping is incorrect and how to correct it? I use a very similar syntax for other link-generation process such as account activation and I do not get this error. Thanks.

Comment: Which Rails version?

Comment: @Val Ascensio. I use rails 4.2.1.

Comment: duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25689691/290338

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> QP works by using the equals sign "=" as an escape character. It also limits line length to 76, as some software has limits on line length. 
>   -- [Quoted Printable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable)

Maybe you are taking the quoted-printable HTML directly from the source of an e-mail. What you saw was in fact escaped according to [Quoted Printable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable) which encodes special characters as `=XX` where `XX` is the characters codepoint in hex. Also the equal signs at line endings will discard the following new line because there has limits on line length of 76 characters.

I don't think you have to care this because this is intended and it's needed for a quoted-printable e-mail as far as you have `Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable` in the header of your mail.

Here's the source code of a real world example, an e-mail from Dropbox.

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: Dropbox <no-reply@dropboxmail.com>
To: xxxxxx@gmail.com
Subject: =?utf-8?q?Upgrade_your_Dropbox!?=
Date: Sat, 8 Aug 2015 11:59:03 +0000
Message-ID: <0000000000@email.amazonses.com>
Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w=
3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns=3D"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><meta content=3D"text/ht=
ml; charset=3Dutf-8" http-equiv=3D"Content-Type"><style> 

.....(snip).....
```

Comment: My understanding is that when using named routes as I did, Rails automatically escapes out any special characters (for instance the "@" of the email address is correctly translated into a "%40"). However, additional encoding is made such as the "=" in the middle of the word "edit" and the "3D" just before the email address. Both makes the URL invalid and I do not think they should be there.

Comment: @Bastien As long as you are using `Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable` in your mail, all `=` must be encoded as `=3B` due to Quoted Printable. Could you please post the full source of the e-mail (especially the headers) rather than the part you think is incorrect?

Comment: Actually you are right. I have more carefully looked at the encoding and indeed it is different. This is the header I get for the erroneous email ----==_mimepart_55c625918863_36e23fd63959670410839
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable.
Whereas this the header I have for the correct email Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="--==_mimepart_55c6278251959_36e23fd624acaf3c11347";
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
So the question is now how do I change the encoding from quoted-printable to 7bit?

Comment: @Bastien You may have characters (such as special symbols, emojis or CJK characters) cannot be represented in `7bit` encoding so it upgraded to quoted-printable. And this encoding is fine for most email clients. Why you must use `7bit`?

Comment: @Bastien Converting a Unicode-compatible encoding to an non-Unicode-compatible encoding is not so good in 2015.

Comment: This is correct. I was using French specific characters which were triggering the change from 7bit to Quoted-Printable.